# Blank screen after boot on 22.04 with amdgpu

Tags: xorg, 22.04, gdm, wayland, amdgpu

I'm having issues after upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 on a Razer Blade 14 RZ09-0370. This laptop comes with an AMD 5900HX CPU with embedded graphics, which is the adapter I'm trying to use. After services are started the screen just goes black and GDM is not loaded. I tried different options.

With the stock 5.15 kernel, I'm getting an error in the kernel logs:

```
[drm:amdgpu_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* VGACON disables amdgpu kernel modesetting.
```

I have tried setting `amdgpu.dc=0` on the kernel command line, it had no effect.

I still have the 5.13 kernel from 20.04 which does boot and I can log into X. However, there is a power issue there, the system is running very loud and hot even though there are no apps running.

I have tried the OEM kernel 5.17, which doesn't have the above issues, but X still doesn't load and I'm not sure why. I'm seeing one issue in the logs:

```
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1801]: AMDGPU(0): Failed to make import prime FD at pixmap: 22
```

If you guys have any ideas what to check, I'd be very grateful.

**EDIT1:** I have reinstalled 20.04.4 and it now comes with a 5.15 kernel, which to my surprise is working.